# How can i get the center of a circleF in Emgu (C#)

Tags: c#, center, geometry, emgucv

After using the HoughCircles method I have some trouble to get the center of the detected circles.
The documentation says I should use the public PointF Center { get; set; } method to get the center of the elements of a CircleF. But VS has a problem to convert the CicleF to an PointF.
I am not so familiar to C# so that I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Documentation Emgu CircleF[]: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/9de6931a-17bc-4125-8b5e-e9f86e68889e.htm
Center of a CircleF: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/b34b6d73-74c6-864e-a33a-1f9c6ce4cee9.htm

The documentation is for me very confusing, so can anybody help me with that problem?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted some code for people to look at, but it sounds like you are trying to assign one type to the wrong type. Think of it like, string s = 3.4 . The types don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Center is a property of type PointF in the CircleF struct, not a method on the PointF struct. Assuming you have a CircleF named circle, use

```
PointF point = circle.Center;
```

To get the center of the circle.

Comment: Thanks, I have a lot more to lern.